# Can't enable windows audio on Windows 8.1

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

I have been having an error with my audio and I have tried to fix it by re-enabling it in services.msc. However when I tried to load it this happened:

This is the error message that occurs:

> Windows could not start the Windows Audio service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 0x800706cc: The endpoint is a duplicate.

[image]

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have AVG antivirus?

Comment: @Jonah Yes I do.

Comment: Look in the AVG Virus Vault (quarantine) for it. There was the same problem a couple days ago and AVG had quarantined it. Restoring it then rebooting should fix the issue.

Comment: What is the file I have to restore?

Comment: Actually, Google says a better method is to do a system restore to before you did Windows Updates (this is what caused AVG to mess up), uninstalling AVG and then doing the updates again.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have a restore point, so should i just uninstall AVG?

Comment: What files are in your quarantine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this I removed all files in my AVG 2014 quarantine which were in the system32 directory. Then I uninstalled AVG and reinstalled it.

Comment: I found that the problem with the Control Panel remained but I was able to fix it by importing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\netprofm key from a working machine. See <http://wintegrity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/how-to-fix-sound-not-working-in-windows.html> for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the endpoing is a duplicate message. I didn't have the file to restore in AVG, and my system restore didn't help. I tried everything I could think of like uninstalling the drivers and uninstalling AVG.

I found a program called Windows Repair from tweaking.com.
I ran the diagnosis with most of the options checked. It took more than 8 hours to run them all, ***but it fixed the problem*** and now my audio is working again.
Not sure if what specific option fixed the problem.